# Setting a default value for a select when select is based on API call

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

I have a function component that takes a list from props and renders a simple select:

```
<AccountForm onSubmit={onAccountSave} countryList={countryList} account={account}></AccountForm>
```

In the compnent i render the select:

```
<select ref={register} className="form-control" name="countryId" disabled={!accountEditMode} >
{props.countryList.map((country, index) => (
    <option key={country.id} value={country.country}>{country.country}</option>
))}
</select>
```

The `countryList` comes from an async call in the main component. I also gets the selected value from a prop. The default value is however not set, properly because I set the default value, before the select has been loaded. How do you handle a scenario like this? Is there an event or something I wait for before setting the value, or what is the right approach here?

Comment: Don't render `<AccountForm />` until you have a real data. For example `{!isLoading && <AccountForm ...props />`

Comment: @MoshFeu but wont you still have the same problem? I get my values async. Both the country list and the selected id. Then I start filling the select while setting the default value. Wont that override the default value as the select maybe has not been filled yet?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `<AccountForm/>` will be rendered only after the data fetched, so you don't have that problem. You'll pass the data and the selected value at once synchronically. BTW, I can't see in your code where you set the default value from the prop.

Comment: @MoshFeu I just tested it and it works perfectly. Thanks! Can you create an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render `<AccountForm />` only after the data been received so it won't have to deal with empty state.

Something like this (This is a "pseudo" implementation)

```
function Component() {
  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCountryList()
      .then(data => {
        setCountryList(data);
        setIsLoading(false)
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {!isLoading &&
      <AccountForm onSubmit={onAccountSave} countryList={countryList} account={account}></AccountForm>
    }
  )
}
```

Or you can check directly if `countryList` is empty, like this:

```
{!countryList.length &&
  <AccountForm onSubmit={onAccountSave} countryList={countryList} account={account}></AccountForm>
}
```

(And there are more options)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the value in the state, and then update the state in the async call? And setting that state value in option value? Just brainstorming.

Comment: Well, brainstorm is not an answer :) I know that you can't comment but you shouldn't commend in an answer..

Comment: So what you mean is have a hook. Set that as defaultValue. And update it. I will try.

Comment: @MoshFeu I know it's not by the rules, but I just wanted to help :) Yes, Thomas, that's the idea. Hope it helps :)